# Generative image in Unity 2d game with using C# System.Drawing or suitable method

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, bitmap, 2d

I'm trying to figure out, what are the best possible way to use generative images in Unity for desktop and Android mobile 2d game applications. Generate directly in build assembly, or import generation some smart way, but I'm not sure what will be such solution if the goal is to get a unique character or object each time user starts the new game.

To generate some simple character or object image in C# Windows desktop application I use:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

with `Brushes`, `Pens` using `DrawEllipse` and other methods with `Bitmap`:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(500, 500, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics g;
```

I've found several similar questions links like [System.Drawing or equivalent.,Getting System.Drawing to work in unity - or alternative library.](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1678854/systemdrawing-or-equivalentgetting-systemdrawing-t.html?_ga=2.46245863.1925595445.1643297325-1590451347.1643297325) and [Bitmaps in unity](https://answers.unity.com/questions/51414/bitmaps-in-unity.html), or [Texture2D.GetPixel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html?_ga=2.46245863.1925595445.1643297325-1590451347.1643297325), [Texture2D.GetPixels](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html) and [Code example in Unity C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline#Code_example_in_Unity_C#) or adding `csc.rsp` in [Using Bitmaps in Unity](https://forum.unity.com/threads/using-bitmaps-in-unity.899168/), but I'm not sure if I'm on the right path, maybe there is some native or an easily integrated way to do that with the same libraries references usage.